# Chiral current VEV below the QCD scale

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, symmetry-breaking, chirality, effective-field-theory

Let's have pure QCD. I know that after spontaneous symmetry breaking quark bilinear form are replaced by their averaged values:
$$
\bar{q}_{i}q_{j} \to \langle \bar{q}_{i}q_{j}\rangle \approx \Lambda_{QCD}^3, \quad \bar{q}_{i}\gamma_{5}q_{j} \to  \langle \bar{q}_{i}\gamma_{5}q_{j}\rangle \approx 0
$$

What can be said about VEVs of $\partial_{\mu}\bar{q}_{i}\gamma^{\mu}\gamma_{5}q_{i}$, 
$$
\int d^4x d^4y\langle 0|T\left(\partial^{x}_{\mu}\bar{q}_{i}\gamma_{\mu}\gamma_{5}q_{i}(x))(\partial^{y}_{\nu}\bar{q}_{i}\gamma^{\nu}\gamma_{5}q_{i}(y))\right)|0\rangle?
$$

An edit. It seems that the second correlator is zero in momentum space for $k \to 0$, since no massless states couples to correlator $\Pi^{\mu \nu}(k) \equiv \int d^{4}x e^{ikx}\langle 0|T(J^{\mu}_{5}(x)J^{\nu}_{5}(0))|0\rangle$ in QCD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the chiral anomaly equation
$$
\partial^\mu \bar{q}_f\gamma_\mu\gamma_5 q_f 
= \frac{N_f}{16\pi^2}
 \tilde{G}^a_{\alpha\beta}G^{a\,\alpha\beta}
$$
this correlator is proportional to the topological susceptibility
$$
\chi_{top}=
\frac{1}{V}\frac{1}{(16\pi^2)^2}\int d^4x \int d^4 y \; \langle T\,
\tilde{G}^a_{\alpha\beta}G^{a\,\alpha\beta}(x)
\tilde{G}^b_{\gamma\delta}G^{b\,\gamma\delta}(y)
\rangle
$$
The topological susceptibility is zero if one of the quarks is massless, but it is non-zero in general, and of $O(\Lambda^4_{QCD})$ in pure gauge theory or the large $N_c$ limit.